# How can I limit memory acquired with `malloc()` without also limiting stack?

Tags: c, malloc, setrlimit

I'm trying to keep student code from running wild with allocations and dragging my test machine to a halt.  I've tried

```
setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, r);
```

where `r` is a struct holding the limits.  But unfortunately although this limit stops `brk` and `sbrk` from allocating, the C library just fails over to `mmap` and keeps right on allocating.

I've also tried

```
setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, r)
```

and this stops the process in its tracks, but this remedy is too severe—it is impossible for the process to recover from the `ENOMEM` error because there's no stack space for the calls the code makes on encountering a `NULL` value returned from `malloc()`.

I have limited controls over the binaries, so if it's possible to do with a system call, I'd prefer that.  But I need some means of capping allocation without destroying the process's ability to recover.  Does anyone have suggestions?

**UPDATE**: I found something called [failmalloc](http://www.nongnu.org/failmalloc/), but it is not very sophisticated, and although I can cause a failure with it, I always get a segfault that gdb cannot diagnose.

**FURTHER UPDATE**: I found that `setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, r)` *does* seem to do the job I want, at least in some cases—the segfaults that were occurring afterward were caused by a fault in an unrelated module.  Unless somebody comes up with something interesting (or a reason to keep the question), I will probably delete the question.

Comment: If you're just trying to prevent abusive/buggy programs from taking down the system, don't bother with letting them recover from failed `malloc`. Just let the OS kill them and be done with it. A correct program presumably should never hit the limit anyway.

Comment: Many students submit incorrect programs.  If they dump core, they get zeroes.  If they recover and abort, the get partial credit.

Answer (score 5):

Building on the idea used by [failmalloc](http://www.nongnu.org/failmalloc/), you could use the [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)<sup>*</sup>
 environment variable and function interposition to build a wrapper around `malloc()` and impose any limitations there.

You would need to dynamically load a pointer to the original `malloc()` using [`dlsym()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html).  You cannot directly call the original `malloc()` from the wrapper because it will be interpreted as a recursive call to the wrapper itself.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void * malloc(size_t size)
{
   static void * (*func)(size_t) = NULL;
   void * ret;

   if (!func)
   {
      /* get reference to original (libc provided) malloc */
      func = (void *(*)(size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
   }

   /* impose any necessary restrictions before calling malloc */
   ...

   /* call original malloc */
   ret = func(size);

   /* impose any necessary restrictions after calling malloc */
   ...

   return ret;
}
```

* Note that `LD_PRELOAD` must specify the full path to the interposer library, and that library interposition is disabled for setuid programs in order to prevent security problems.

---

An [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998464/function-interposition-in-linux-without-dlsym/998489#998489) to using [`dlsym()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) would be to use the GNU linker `--wrap symbol` option.

Comment: The valgrind sources should contain something similar to that approach, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Can you force a macro on the unsuspecting students? :-)

```
#define malloc(bytes) limited_malloc(bytes)
```

and also a definition for `limited_malloc` that limits what can be done.