# How to do Binary instrumentation of syscall brk ? (x86-64 Linux) (maybe valgrind?)

Tags: valgrind, sandbox, x86-64, instrumentation, opcode

I'd like to instrument [`syscall brk`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html) (and other calls but this in first order, it's most important to me) in *given binary* (preferably on actual syscall/sysenter level (x86-64 and x86) of making [`sys_brk`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.4.3/include/linux/syscalls.h#L455) call).

Main goal:

- A part of sandbox which gives *fixed amount* of memory to jailed process
- So, I'd like to get rid of [`brk`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html) system calls (and most preferably others in next order) and simulate memory allocations under *fixed limit*. *Fixed limit* is memory space, available to program. (You can think about it like making a kind of sandbox with fixed amount of available memory)

How to implement (one of) some example possible solutions (or yours solution):

- just changing instructions to [`NOP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)
- As `brk` returns 0 on success, simulate it's successes with setting operations that sets memory (register) state , as [`brk`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html) would be called with success.
- More complex... instrument with code (or function call) which simulates success memory allocations under fixed limit.
- Most flexible (maybe overkill in my case) to change this syscall into function call and add provided function to binary.

*Given binary* is code that can be malicious in one of two (most preferably both :) ) forms:

- shared library - here I can setup environment before function call (for example do brk call in controlled way)
- program binary - in this case we need to give program *fixed amount* of memory (by caller, or on begining of program "one syscall"), cause it can not allocate. Example of calling such program should be included in answer.

As problem is highly connected with many other aspects, I tried do my best in separating it as question, but please give me advice if I should specify something more or less.

Answers with implementation, links to resources (books, tutorials) are welcome.

(I am most interested in **Linux**, and solution that is *reliable*, so that people preparing binaries, even in assembler, would not have to worry about execution of their code)

Answer (score 1):

LD_PRELOAD will trap C calls to brk(), but it won't trap the actual system call (int/syscall instruction).  There's no portable way to trap those, but on Linux, [ptrace](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100) will do it.  Memory can also be allocated to a program by mmap(), so you'll need to intercept that call too.

Of course, what it seems you're really looking for is [rlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)().

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, portability issues. I've narrowed question to Linux, to make easy finding solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't think you want valgrind for this.

You can use LD_PRELOAD or linker tricks to capture brk(2): see these other discussions:

[Function interposition in Linux without dlsym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998464/function-interposition-in-linux-without-dlsym)

[Overriding 'malloc' using the LD_PRELOAD mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism)

Code might look like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

/* prototype int brk(void *addr); */

static int (*real_brk)(void *addr) = NULL;

int brk(void * addr) {

    real_brk = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "brk");
    if (real_brk == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error mapping brk: %s\n", dlerror());
            return -1;
    }
    printf("calling brk(2) for %p\n", addr);
    return (real_brk (addr));
}`
```

and then LD_PRELOAD that to intercept brk(2)

Comment: This answer wouldn't work on Linux for at least two reasons: the dynamic loader will itself call `brk()`, both before and afer processing `LD_PRELOAD`. The calls brefore will go un-intercepted, and the calls after will likely cause infinite recursion, as `dlsym` may itself dynamically allocate memory.