# Computing the set of writes when executing a function

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, operating-system

I want to write a function `computeWriteSet` that takes an arbitrary function `f` as an argument and (1) executes the function `f` and (2) returns the set of *places* modified or written to (addresses/pages/objects) during `f`'s execution.

```
writeset computeWriteSet(function f) {
  writeset ws = createEmptyWriteset();
  // prepare to execute f
  startRecordingWrites(&ws);
  f();
  stopRecordingWrites(&ws);
  // post-process the write-set
  return ws;
}
```

1. What options exist for implementing it?
2. What are their tradeoffs (in which case which implementation is more efficient and what are the limitations?)

## Notes

The function is specified at runtime and can do anything (i.e. can contain any set of instructions, including loops, branching and function/system calls.

All writes from the time `f` is called until it returns should be recorded (this includes functions called from within `f` itself). For simplicity, let's assume `computeWriteSet` is not called from within.

OS-specific *tricks* are allowed (and probably required). I'm particularly interested in **Linux**, ideally within userspace.

## Example

```
static int x = 0;
static int y = 0;
static int z = 0;

void a() {
  if (y) z++;
  if (x) y++;
  x = (x + 1) % 2;
}

int main() {
  computeWriteSet(a); // returns { &x }     => {x,y,z} = {1, 0, 0}
  computeWriteSet(a); // returns { &x, &y } => {x,y,z} = {0, 1, 0}
  computeWriteSet(a); // returns { &x, &z } => {x,y,z} = {1, 1, 1}
  return 0;
}
```

## Expected Output

The output should be the set of *changes*. This can be either the set of pages:

```
{ <address of x>, <address of y>, …}
```

Or the set of memory addresses:

```
{<page of x and y>, <page of z>, …}
```

Or the set of objects ( (based on interposition of allocation functions)

```
x = malloc(100) // returns address 0xAAA
y = malloc(200) // returns address 0xBBB
…

{ {address, size}, {0xAAA, 100}, {0xBBB, 200}, … }
```

The return value is loosely specified on purpose -- different techniques will have different spatial resolution and different overheads.

#### Please note:

**This is a highly uncommon programming question, hence if you think it should be closed let me know why and, ideally, how to phrase/place it so that it follows the guidelines. :-)**

Comment: The sourcecode of `valgrind`/`memcheck` may contain what you want.

Comment: I suspect the way those programs work is by using `mprotect` to mark the memory read-only. Then any memory modifications trigger a signal, and a handler keeps track of what memory it was trying to modify.

Comment: continuing @Barmar thought. After you detect the write into a read-only page, you would need to set protection to write and repeat the operation (this is what a debugger typically does when it watches writes).  This would be awfully slow though.

Comment: there is no good way for doing what you asked for. It would require instrumentation of the code, similar to valgrind, or other tools. The trade off will be run time performance and extra compilation or run steps. Also a lot of headache to develop (or reuse) this feature.

Comment: If you are looking for tools, which can help you in your task, then your question is off-topic as "**software recommendation**" one. If you want to collect *ideas*, then the question is off-topic as "**open-ended**". If you want to have an answer, which *completely* describes a way for achieve what do you want, then such answer would be **too long** for Stack Overflow format. You need to reduce the scope of the question by selecting an instrumentation tool, and ask specifically about applying this tool for a specific task.

Comment: I would look at either linking in your own malloc/free replacement, or capturing system calls like brk.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7968993/10396)  for some ideas .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Barmar, one way of accomplishing this is via `mprotect`.

This will generate one exception for each of the memory pages, which may add considerable overhead depending on the function. This exception is handled by us and we then insert the corresponding address into a set.

A small 100-line `C++`/`C` fully-contained messy program showcasing this is included below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

extern "C" {
extern int __data_start;
extern int _end;
}

#define PAGE_SIZE sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)
#define PAGE_MASK (PAGE_SIZE - 1)
#define PAGE_ALIGN_DOWN(x) (((intptr_t) (x)) & ~PAGE_MASK)
#define PAGE_ALIGN_UP(x) ((((intptr_t) (x)) + PAGE_MASK) & ~PAGE_MASK)
#define GLOBALS_START PAGE_ALIGN_DOWN((intptr_t) &__data_start)
#define GLOBALS_END   PAGE_ALIGN_UP((intptr_t) &_end - 1)
#define GLOBALS_SIZE  (GLOBALS_END - GLOBALS_START)

std::set<void*> *addresses = new std::set<void*>();

void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ctx) {
    void *addr = siginfo->si_addr;
    void *aligned_addr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(PAGE_ALIGN_DOWN(addr));
    switch(siginfo->si_code) {
    case SEGV_ACCERR:
        mprotect(aligned_addr, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
        addresses->insert(aligned_addr);
        break;
    default:
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void computeWriteSet(std::function<void()> f) {
    static bool initialized = false;
    if (!initialized) {
        // install signal handler
        stack_t sigstk;
        sigstk.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
        sigstk.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
        sigstk.ss_flags = 0;
        sigaltstack(&sigstk, NULL);
        struct sigaction siga;
        sigemptyset(&siga.sa_mask);
        sigaddset(&siga.sa_mask, SIGSEGV);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &siga.sa_mask, NULL);
        siga.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK | SA_RESTART | SA_NODEFER;
        siga.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &siga, NULL);
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &siga.sa_mask, NULL);
        initialized = true;
    }
    addresses->clear();
    printf("\nexecuting function\n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    mprotect(reinterpret_cast<void*>(GLOBALS_START), GLOBALS_SIZE, PROT_READ);
    f();
    mprotect(reinterpret_cast<void*>(GLOBALS_START), GLOBALS_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("pages written:\n");
    for (auto addr : *addresses) {
        printf("%p\n", addr);
    }
}

void f() {
    static int x[1024] = {0};
    static int y[1024] = {0};
    static int z[1024] = {0};
    static bool firsttime = true;
    if (firsttime) {
        printf("&x[0] = %p\n&y[0] = %p\n&z[0] = %p\n", x, y, z);
        firsttime = false;
    }
    if (y[0]) z[0]++;
    if (x[0]) y[0]++;
    x[0] = (x[0] + 1) % 2;
    printf("{x, y, z} = {%d, %d, %d}\n", x[0], y[0], z[0]);
}

int main() {
    computeWriteSet(f);
    computeWriteSet(f);
    computeWriteSet(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using `g++ --std=c++11 example.cpp`.

Execution prints something like:

```
executing function
--------------
&x[0] = 0x6041c0
&y[0] = 0x6051c0
&z[0] = 0x6061c0
{x, y, z} = {1, 0, 0}
--------------
pages written:
0x604000

executing function
--------------
{x, y, z} = {0, 1, 0}
--------------
pages written:
0x604000
0x605000

executing function
--------------
{x, y, z} = {1, 1, 1}
--------------
pages written:
0x604000
0x606000
```

Some notes:

- We make `x`, `y` and `z` large-enough arrays (of size `PAGE_SIZE/sizeof(int)`, which is 1024 on my machine) so that they fall in different memory pages and therefore can be differentiated.
- This program will only work for global/static variables so that it can be short-ish. To extend it to work with heaps and other memory mappings can be done via interpositions, as suggested by @AShelly.

On-topic follow-up: Is there any way of avoiding the `O(N)` signals, where `N` is the number of pages written to?