# malloc function interposition in the standard C and C++ libraries

Tags: c, unix, malloc, shared-libraries, function-interposition

I want to write a shared library in such a way that it is possible to isolate it’s memory usage from the application it is linked against. That is, if the shared library, let’s call it `libmemory.so`, calls `malloc`, I want to maintain that memory in a separate heap from the heap that is used to service calls to `malloc` made in the application. This question isn't about writing memory allocators, it more about linking and loading the library and application together.

So far I’ve been experimenting with combinations of function interposition, symbol visibility, and linking tricks. So far, I can’t get this right because of one thing: the standard library. I cannot find a way to distinguish between calls to the standard library that internally use `malloc` that happen in `libmemory.so` versus the application. This causes an issue since then any standard library usage within `libmemory.so` pollutes the application heap.

My current strategy is to interpose definitions of `malloc` in the shared library as a hidden symbol. This works nicely and all of the library code works as expected except, of course, the standard library which is loaded dynamically at runtime. Naturally, I’ve been trying to find a way to statically embed the standard library usage so that it would use the interposed `malloc` in `libmemory.so` at compile time. I’ve tried `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` without success (and anyway, it seems this is discouraged). Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998464/function-interposition-in-linux-without-dlsym) the right answer?

What do?

P.s., further reading is always appreciated, and help on the question tagging front would be nice.

Comment: Unlike Windows, the Unix userland is very strongly biased toward everything in a process using the same allocator. Merely *having* two implementations of `malloc` in the same process is liable to cause catastrophic malfunctions, because nobody worries about matching A_malloc with A_free and B_malloc with B_free, the implementations might get in a fight over which of them is allowed to call `sbrk` with a nonzero argument, etc. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Therefore, in order to give any sort of helpful answer, we need to know a whole lot more about why you think you need to do this thing in the first place.  What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?  Why does this seem like the path of least resistance?  It would also be useful to know generally what `libmemory.so` does and which C and C++ library functions it uses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zwol. I'm building a distributed shared memory allocator as a shared object and want to find a way to separate memory used by the shared object versus the application. The shared object is complex: it has a allocator, has an embedded HTTP sever, etc. It makes ample use of memory itself (albeit, memory from a special allocator that I use throughout all the library code I write). The problem, as state, is the memory the standard library uses... e.g. , a fall to `fopen` or `gmtime_r` might internally call malloc, thereby using the *application's* heap allocator to be used.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is: maybe the bulk of what the shared library does should be extracted to a separate daemon process.

Comment: That is a substantial design change but is certainly possible. Are there any other approaches I can investigate with my current setup before I change course?

Comment: I realize now that you didn't really answer my question.  Why is it *bad* for the memory allocated directly or indirectly by your shared-object allocator to be lumped with the memory allocated by the application?

Comment: I've been mulling this question over in my head, too. From a purist's point of view this just feels dirty. I would _prefer_ to keep the memory separate if possible. It is sounding like what I was is simply not possible, which makes the question you're asking more important. I think it may not matter, it is just distasteful, since I would be mixing local per process memory with a the distributed application's memory. Maybe I'll look into your daemon idea more, that achieves complete isolation.

Answer (score 2):

> I’ve tried -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ without success

Of *course* this wouldn't succeed: `malloc` doesn't live in `libgcc` or `libstdc++`; it lives in `libc`.

What you want to do is *statically* link `libmemory.so` with some alternative `malloc` implementation, such as [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) or [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc), and *hide* all `malloc` symbols. Then your library and your application will have absolutely separate heaps.

It goes without saying that you must *never* allocate something in your library and free it in the application, or vice versa.

In theory you could also link the `malloc` part of system `libc.a` into your library, but in practice GLIBC (and most other UNIX C libraries) does not support partially-static link (if you link `libc.a`, you must not link `libc.so`).

**Update:**

> If libmemory.so makes use of a standard library function, e.g., gmtime_r, which is linked in dynamically, thereby resolving malloc at runtime, then libmemory.so mistakenly uses malloc provided at runtime (the one apparently from glibc

There is *nothing* mistaken about that. Since you've hidden your `malloc` inside your library, there is *no* other `malloc` that `gmtime_r` could use.

Also, `gmtime_r` doesn't allocate memory, except for internal use by GLIBC itself, and such memory could be cleaned up by `__libc_freeres`, so it would be *wrong* to allocate this memory anywhere other than using GLIBC's `malloc`.

Now, `fopen` is another example you used, and `fopen` does `malloc` memory. Apparently you would like `fopen` to call your `malloc` (even though it's not visible to `fopen`) when called by your library, but call system `malloc` when called by the application. But how can `fopen` know who called it? Surely you are not suggesting that `fopen` walk the stack to figure out whether it was called by your library or by something else?

So, if you really want to make your library *never* call into system `malloc`, then you would have to statically link *all* other libc functions that you use and that may call `malloc` (and hide them in your library as well).

You could use something like `uclibc` or `dietlibc` to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am linking `libmemory.so` with my own `malloc` symbols and I am also hiding these symbols in `libmemory.so`. `libmemory.so`'s use of malloc is taken care of perfectly fine. The problem, per the original question, is in regards to the standard library. If `libmemory.so` makes use of a standard library function, e.g., `gmtime_r`, which is linked in dynamically, thereby resolving `malloc` at runtime, then `libmemory.so` mistakenly uses `malloc` provided at runtime (the one apparently from `glibc` -- thanks for that). Does this clarify, or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, this is aligned with how I am thinking about the problem. I was under the impression that I couldn't use something like `uclibc`, `dietlibc`, or `musl` without replacing `libc` for the entire application. It sounds like you're suggesting that statically linking _all_ libc functions that `libmemory.so` uses can be done (thereby using `libmemory.so`'s internal malloc implementation) without touching the application: it would still use the normal dynamically linked libc.

Comment: is this impression incorrect? Can I build `musl` and statically link it to my `libmemory.so` without screwing up the other `libc`?